# Change where certain generated resources are placed

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I currently have two projects; one for the server-side ([Akka-HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/index.html)) and one for the client-side ([ScalaJS](https://www.scala-js.org/)). The client-side generates the `.js` files I want to serve using the server-side. To give the server-side access to those files, I added this `build.sbt` entry in the server-side project:

```
lazy val server = project.in(file("server"))
  ...
  .settings(
    (resourceGenerators in Compile) <+= Def.task {
      val f1 = (fullOptJS in client).value.data
      val f1sm = f1.getParentFile / (f1.getName + ".map")
      f1 :: f1sm :: (packageMinifiedJSDependencies in client).value :: Nil
    }
  )
```

This, however, puts my `.js` and `.map` files inside the root of the `classes` folder. Since I want to serve my assets like so:

```
pathPrefix("assets") {
  ...
  pathPrefix("client") {
    getFromResourceDirectory("<directory where .js and .map files are placed>")
  }
}
```

with emphasis on the `#getFromResourceDirectory` method, this isn't going to work with my assets inside the root of my `classes` folder. My `application.conf` is placed in the same directory as the generated files which would make that available for the whole world to see.

What I would like is my `.js` and `.map` files inside a sub-directory of the `classes` directory. Something like `client/` so I can use the `#getFromResourceDirectory` method like `getFromResourceDirectory("client")` and don't worry my configuration file is available to the outside world.

My question - ***How do I achieve this?***

I already tried adding:

```
lazy val client = project.in(file("client"))
  ...
  .settings(inConfig(Compile)((fullOptJS :: packageMinifiedJSDependencies :: Nil)
    .map(a => (crossTarget in a) ~= (_ / "client")))
  )
```

to my client-side project which only places the generated `.js` and `.map` files in a client folder in the client-side project its `scala-2.11` folder:

[image: client-side target overview]

but the setting does not propagate to the server-side project its `classes` folder:

[image: server-side target overview]

### This is the desired situation:

[image: server-side target overview desired]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diving into SBT let me down the following path; Firstly, I inspected `server/compile:resourceGenerators` (using `sbt inspect server/compile:resourceGenerators`):

```
[info] ...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:discoveredSbtPlugins
[info]  server/compile:resourceManaged
[info]  client/compile:packageMinifiedJSDependencies
[info]  client/compile:fullOptJS
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:managedResources
[info] ...
```

I then inspected `server/compile:managedResources`:

```
[info] ...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:resourceGenerators
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:resources
[info] ...
```

I then inspected `server/compile:resources`:

```
[info] ...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:managedResources
[info]  server/compile:unmanagedResources
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:copyResources
[info] ...
```

I then inspected `server/compile:copyResources`:

```
[info] ...
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:295
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  server/compile:classDirectory
[info]  server/compile:resources
[info]  server/compile:resourceDirectories
[info]  server/compile:copyResources::streams
[info] ...
```

I then inspected the `Defaults.scala` file from SBT on line 295:

```
copyResources <<= copyResourcesTask
```

I then inspected this `copyResourcesTask` definition:

```
def copyResourcesTask =
  (classDirectory, resources, resourceDirectories, streams) map { (target, resrcs, dirs, s) =>
    val cacheFile = s.cacheDirectory / "copy-resources"
    val mappings = (resrcs --- dirs) pair (rebase(dirs, target) | flat(target))
    s.log.debug("Copy resource mappings: " + mappings.mkString("\n\t", "\n\t", ""))
    Sync(cacheFile)(mappings)
    mappings
  }
```

The `mappings` val is very important in this case. It creates the mappings between the paths created by the various tasks responsible for all the resources and the final path these resources will receive in the `target` folder. The [`#rebase`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Mapping-Files.html#Rebase) method is (mostly) responsible for these mappings but it falls back on the [`#flat`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Mapping-Files.html#Flatten) method if not a single `resourceDirectories` entry is in the path of the resource. By simply adding the `crossTarget` path of my client-side project to the `resourceDirectories` setting, rebase replaces everything up until the `client/<filename>` part of my `.js` and `.map` files instead of falling-back on the `#flat` method and only replacing the `<filename>` part which, combined with this setting:

```
lazy val client = project.in(file("client"))
  ...
  .settings(inConfig(Compile)((fullOptJS :: packageMinifiedJSDependencies :: Nil)
    .map(a => (crossTarget in a) ~= (_ / "client")))
  )
```

is exactly the behavior I want.

---

### TL;DR

Add to your client-side project:

```
.settings(inConfig(Compile)((fullOptJS :: packageMinifiedJSDependencies :: Nil)
  .map(a => (crossTarget in a) ~= (_ / "client")))
)
```

Add to your server-side project:

```
.settings(inConfig(Compile)((resourceGenerators <+= Def.task {
  val f1 = (fullOptJS in client).value.data
  val f1sm = f1.getParentFile / (f1.getName + ".map")
  f1 :: f1sm :: (packageMinifiedJSDependencies in client).value :: Nil
}) :: (resourceDirectories += (crossTarget in client).value) :: Nil))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn, thx for the great solution.

This is real help me a lot.
little update here.

for frontend/client settings.

```
  .settings(inConfig(Compile)(
    (fullOptJS :: fastOptJS :: packageScalaJSLauncher
     :: packageJSDependencies :: packageMinifiedJSDependencies :: Nil)
      .map(f => (crossTarget in f) ~= (_ / "sjsout"))
  ))
```

for backend/server settings.

```
  .settings(
    (resourceGenerators in Compile) += Def.task {
      val fastJsOut = (fastOptJS in Compile in frontend).value.data
      val fastJsSourceMap = fastJsOut.getParentFile / (fastJsOut.getName + ".map")
      val fullJsOut = (fullOptJS in Compile in frontend).value.data
      val fullJsSourceMap = fullJsOut.getParentFile / (fullJsOut.getName + ".map")
      Seq(
        fastJsOut,
        fastJsSourceMap,
        //fullJsOut,
        //fullJsSourceMap,
        (packageScalaJSLauncher in Compile in frontend).value.data,
        (packageJSDependencies in Compile in frontend).value
        //(packageMinifiedJSDependencies in Compile in frontend).value
      )
    }.taskValue,
    (resourceDirectories in Compile) += (crossTarget in frontend).value,
    watchSources ++= (watchSources in frontend).value
  )
```